# validation not working in cake php if i use $this->Form->textarea()

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

validation work i use ($this->Form->input)

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Car', array('type'=>'textarea','label'=>false, 'cols'=>'23', 'rows'=>'4'));?>
```

and if i use ($this->Form->textarea) validation not work

```
<?php echo $this->Form->textarea('Car', array('label'=>false, 'cols'=>'23', 'rows'=>'4'));?>
```

but output is same both line of code

could anyone tell me why it's happening ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Validation* is still working. What is not working is the *display of the error*.

`FormHelper::input` does a lot of work, including output of validation errors.
`FormHelper::textarea` only outputs a textarea, nothing more. You have to output the error yourself using `echo $this->Form->error('Car')`.

Comment: I would recommend `FormHelper::input` indeed (`FormHelper::control` in CakePHP 3).